# Finding the centers of overlapping rectangles in 2d NumPy array

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have a 2D NumPy array with several potentially overlapping rectangles of variable size. How can I compute the coordinates of the centers of each rectangle? In the attached image, my objective is to compute the coordinates of the red dots.

The array is all zeros, except for the pixels that indicate the rectangle borders, which have value one. In the example image, the black pixels have value zero, and the white pixels have value one.

[image]

Comment: What does the array look like? Just corner coordinates? Please post the code.

Comment: How do you know, in your picture, whether what looks like two intersecting rectangles is not, in fact, three rectangles?

Comment: Can more than two rectangles overlap simultaneously ? Can edges overlap on more than a point ?

Comment: @dmuir that's a good point, I don't think it is possible to determine this. However, for my application, it's sufficient to choose one of the two arbitrarily.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, more than two rectangles can overlap simultaneously. The edges are currently 3 pixels wide, so they can overlap on more than a point.

Comment: @tmakino: I mean, can they overlap along a segment ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, they can

Comment: This is bad news because it can lead to ambiguous situations.

Comment: @tmakino there is a lot of possible ambiguity. Consider for example a 3x1 and a 1x3 centred at the same point. The same pattern could be 5 1x1 squares, or 4 squares (missout the middle one) or various combinations of 1x1 and 1x2 and 2x1 and ...

Answer (score 0):

Search the image row by row, starting from the (0, 0) corner. The first nonzero pixel that you encounter must be the top left corner of a rectangle. Follow the pixels to the right until you hit the top right corner, then down, then left, and finally up again. If you end up at the same pixel as where you started, it was a full rectangle.

Keep track of all pixels that were identified as being part of a rectangle, so that you won't trace them again.

Edit:
A requirement for this algorithm is that the corners of different rectangles don't touch each other. With 3-pixel-wide borders, the algorithm will trace the outer pixels of the rectangle. It will also attempt to trace the two 1-pixel wide rectangles inside the outer one, but these are discarded.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def search_rectangles(img):
    """Search rectangles in 2D boolean image array.
    
    Return: rectangles - array shape (n, 3, 2) for n rectangles.
       rectangles[i, 0, :] represents the top left corner [i, j]
       recnangles[i, 1, :] represents the bottom right corner [i, j]
       rectangles[i, 2, :] represents the center (rounded as integer).
    """
    
    seen = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.bool)
    ny, nx = img.shape
    rectangles = []
    
    for i in range(ny):
        for j in range(nx):
            if img[i, j] == 0 or seen[i, j]:
                continue
            # new rectangle pixel; assume it's the top left corner.
            # follow it clockwise.
            didjs = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]
            ii, jj = i, j
            corners = np.array([[i, j], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]])
            for k, (di, dj) in enumerate(didjs):
                if k == 2:
                    # opposite corner
                    corners[1, :] = [ii, jj]
                while img[ii+di, jj+dj]:
                    ii += di
                    jj += dj
                    seen[ii, jj] = True
            if (ii, jj) == (i, j):
                corners[2, :] = np.around(corners[:2, :].mean(axis=1))
                rectangles.append(corners)
    
    return np.array(rectangles)

def draw_rectangle(img, i0, i1, j0, j1):
    """Draw rectangle with 3px border width."""
    img[i0:i1+1, j0:j0+3] = 1
    img[i0:i1+1, j1-2:j1+1] = 1
    img[i0:i0+3, j0:j1+1] = 1
    img[i1-2:i1+1, j0:j1+1] = 1


# test case
img = np.zeros((100, 150), dtype=np.uint8)
draw_rectangle(img, 10, 40, 20, 50)
draw_rectangle(img, 15, 34, 25, 44)
draw_rectangle(img, 20, 70, 70, 90)
draw_rectangle(img, 50, 90, 75, 120)

plt.close('all')
plt.imshow(img)
print(search_rectangles(img))
```

Output:

[image: Overlapping rectangles]

```
[[[ 10  20]
  [ 40  50]
  [ 15  45]]

 [[ 15  25]
  [ 34  44]
  [ 20  39]]

 [[ 20  70]
  [ 70  90]
  [ 45  80]]

 [[ 50  75]
  [ 90 120]
  [ 62 105]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the information you have.

If you have the coordinates of the bottom left and top right corners, then the center will be the average between the two.

If you have one corner and the dimensions, then you can just move from the corner to the center using half the dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

# Bottom left and top right
bl = np.array([1, 0])
tr = np.array([2, 1])

center = np.mean((bl, tr), axis = 0)

# Bottom left corner and dimensions

bl = np.array([1, 0])
dimensions = np.array([1, 1])

center = bl + 0.5 * dimensions
```